# "Cannot open source file" error with existing file and correct path

Tags: c++, qt, msbuild, cl

I'm building some custom Qt components as a static library, but I can't get past the compilation phase.
My project is structured as follows:

```
Root:
 - .h and . cpp files of the custom Qt components
 - GeneratedFiles/Debug/ <-- here the MOC compiler puts the generated moc_*.cpp files ("Debug" is automatically deducted from the build configuration, so it's Release for release builds)
```

That's a pretty standard folder setup, but for whatever reason the compiler can't find *only the moc files*. Anything that is in the root folder builds just fine, but the moc files are not found. Please note, **the moc_ files are generated just fine and exist where they're supposed to be, with the correct content**. The problem seems to be in the evaluation of the path `GeneratedFiles\Debug\moc_whatever.cpp`.

Interestingly enough, if I move a moc file (say, `moc_example.cpp`) in the root folder and manually adapt the call to `CL.exe` to compile `moc_example.cpp` instead of `GeneratedFiles\Debug\moc_example.cpp`, the file gets built.

I'm using VS 2017 version 15.7.1, CL is version 19.00.24215.1 for x64 and I'll update the question with any other detail might be useful, just add ask in a comment.

So... Why is the compiler telling me those files do not exist?

Comment: I've found problems with the Qt VS addon relatd to the moc'ing process, usually related to some of them _unexpectedly_ excluded from project. I've had to fix them manually (in the project file). You can take a look at the .vcxproj file to check the paths are correct there, maybe an undefined envvar?

Comment: The problem is unrelated to the vcproj file. Trying to build via command line with a direct `cl.exe` invocation raises the same error. Also, excluding the `moc_*.cpp` file from the built sources and forcefully `#include`-ing at the end of the relative `*.cpp` (and adding all the necessary include dirs) also causes the same problem. Again, if I move the files to the root directory, everything compiles. So far my best guess is "black magic is at work".

Answer (score 5):

I finally solved this rebuilding the directory structure in a new directory. Apparently, using WSL's git to check out repositories under Windows breaks something in the filesystem in a way that is invisible from Explorer or Ubuntu's command line, but that breaks the compiler (and Visual Studio's intellisense).

Checking out the repository with Git for Windows seems to avoid causing the same problem.